# EF Core get rows from cursor output parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which has cursor output parameter like this:

```
create stored procedure ProcedureName
    (@param1 varchar, 
     @pcursor CURSOR VARYING OUTPUT)
as
begin
    ...
end
```

The cursor is linked to multicolumn value.

How can I get all rows from EF Core or standard `SqlCommand`?

```
var param1 = new SqlParameter 
                 {
                     ParameterName = "param1",
                     Value = "value",
                     DbType = DbType.String,
                     Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                 };

var pOutput= new SqlParameter
                 {
                     ParameterName = "pcursor",
                     DbType = DbType.???,
                     Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                 };

context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec ProcedureName @param1, @pcursor output", param1, pOutput);

pOutput.Value ????
```

Comment: Why use a cursor *at all*? Especially with an ORM which returns *all* objects at once? Even if you used pure ADO.NET and SqlCommand, using cursors is a very bad idea , no matter the database

Comment: I'm absolutely agree, but thats created by another team. Maybе i can wrap it with another function, or use virtual table for result aggregation?

Comment: Tell them to rewrite this. Cursors like this are almost useless in T-SQL - if one wanted to use the results, one should use a VIEW or a table-valued function. They simply can't be used with an ORM. What you posted looks like an attempt to rewrite an Oracle stored procedure for SQL Server

Comment: Cursors are great in Oracle.  They are really not appropriate to use with SQL Server

Comment: _created by another team_ Development teams are supposed to cooperate. To do that, they need to communicate. They also need to design code resources in a manner that is effective and efficient for the consumer of those resources.

Answer (score 0):

For get output parameters use below code

```
    public static List<SqlParameter> EXEC_StoredProc(string storedProcName, params SqlParameter[] sqlParameters)
    {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            using (con)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcName, con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters);
                    if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) con.Open();
    
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
                    if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
    
                    return sqlParameters.Where(A=>A.Direction == ParameterDirection.Output).ToList();
                }
            }
    }
```

**Call function**

```
var output = EXEC_StoredProc("myStProc", new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.BigInt) { Value = 5}, new SqlParameter("@Result", SqlDbType.Bit) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output }).First().Value;
```